# cart icon on top bar not showing added products in my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, cart

I have an e-commerce site. The problem is that top bar cart icon acting weird sometimes it is displaying added cart products data and most of the time not. why having this issue?.looking for code free solutions to resolve this issue.any plugin
i m also attaching screenshot of the page to clarify the problem.

[screenshot of website showing top cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxGev.jpg)

I want top cart to show added products.